# How do you jump instantly upon starting the dungeon in King of Thieves?

Tags: king-of-thieves

Some player's dungeons kill me instantly unless I jump immediately upon entering. This is practically impossible for me; no matter how quickly I double-tap, I can only rarely perform this jump. Actually, it doesn't even work at all anymore! Is there any trick to pulling this off? I have to skip a lot of dungeons because they have traps right near the door, or the door in midair... I reported this issue to the devs, but they say it is possible to pull off with skill!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - you have to tap 3 times in a row when you start the dungeon. Not sure why tapping twice doesn't work!